# Unable to delete registry keys from batch file or VBS

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a batch file which deletes registry entries from a computer, the batch file has the following lines.

```
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test\Installation\Test-x64-9.2 /f > remove.log 2>&1
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test\Service\Test-x64-9.2 /f > remove.log 2>&1
```

This batch file is called by the Installer (InstallAnywhere I guess). when the installer runs and executes this batch file, the remove.log states:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

When I run this batch file manually, it works fine. I thought there was some issue with the batch file, so i created a VBScript to delete the Reg entries. same thing again.
when I run the vbs manually, it deleted the reg keys but when the same vbs is called by the installer, it doesnot delete the reg entries.

If permissions was the problem, then I guess I would have received a `permission denied`  error. which did not. It just says `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Could still be a permissions issue. It's possible the installer is writing a generic log entry when the registry key removal fails. It may not be catching specific exceptions and writing specific error descriptions. Have you tried running the installer/uninstaller with Admin permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running the installer with admin permissions.. Also the remove.log is created by the batch file not the installer itself... so not sure if its a permissions issue or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this Vbscript

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell,MyKey1,MyKey2,MyKeys,i
MyKey1 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test\Installation\Test-x64-9.2"
MyKey2 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test\Service\Test-x64-9.2"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyKeys = Array(MyKey1,MyKey2)
For i = LBound(MyKeys) To UBound(MyKeys)
    If RegExists(MyKeys(i)) = True Then
        WshShell.RegDelete(MyKeys(i))
        Msgbox "The key " & DblQuote(MyKeys(i)) & " is deleted ! ",VbInformation,DblQuote(MyKeys(i))
    Else
        Msgbox "ERROR " & VbTab & Err.Description & VbCrLF & "The key " & DblQuote(MyKeys(i)) & " NOT FOUND ! ",VbCritical,DblQuote(MyKeys(i))
    End if
Next
'************************************************************************
Function RegExists(value)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WS
    Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    val = WS.RegRead(value)
    If (Err.number = -2147024893) or (Err.number = -2147024894) Then
        RegExists = False
    Else
        RegExists = True
    End If
End Function
'************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with your installer - there are similar probs on the right hand side of this page. Use the /reg:64 parameter. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948698/en-au